# knitr creating a wrong second "#" in a deep hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, r, links, knitr, rstudio

I would like to compile a `.Rnw` Document in RStudio with `knitr` that includes a "#" in the hyperlink (deeplink) of a float caption.

See the minimum working example: 
*(compiled with R Studio Version 0.99.435, pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian))*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

<<TestPlot, fig.cap='\\href{http://amor.cms.hu-berlin.de/~schulzgu/gentri/#mieteaenderung}{Click here and u will see the link contains \\#\\# instead of \\#}', echo=FALSE>>=
plot(rnorm(30))
@
In contrast, a plain Latex Link containing a \# in the URL works:
\href{http://amor.cms.hu-berlin.de/~schulzgu/gentri/#mieteaenderung}{Click here}
\end{document}
```

The PDF compiles, but the hyperlink in the caption now contains **TWO** "#" instead of one - consequently leading the reader to a wrong URL.

It seems that knitr inserts a second # when in fact there should only be one.

**Any workarounds for this or even a proper solution?**

---

The `.log` file gives me the following errors:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \GetTitleStringResult.
<to be read again> 
               m
l.58 ...see the link contains \#\# instead of \#}}
                                              \label{fig:TestPlot}
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \GTS@GlobalString.
<to be read again> 
               m
l.58 ...see the link contains \#\# instead of \#}}
                                              \label{fig:TestPlot}
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

 ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
               m
l.58 ...see the link contains \#\# instead of \#}}
                                              \label{fig:TestPlot}
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
               m
l.58 ...see the link contains \#\# instead of \#}}
                                              \label{fig:TestPlot}
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
               m
l.58 ...see the link contains \#\# instead of \#}}
                                              \label{fig:TestPlot}
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
    <to be read again> 
               m
l.58 ...see the link contains \#\# instead of \#}}
                                              \label{fig:TestPlot}
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 67.
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character # in the link defined in the caption needs to be escaped with a double backslash.

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

<<TestPlot, fig.cap="\\href{http://amor.cms.hu-berlin.de/~schulzgu/gentri/\\#mieteaenderung}{If you escape the character \\# in the link with a double backslash, then everything is fine.}", echo=FALSE>>=
plot(rnorm(30))
@

This is a special situation connected with the chunk elaborated by R. You don't need to add the escape characters in plain \LaTeX in the case of a link to a URL containing a \# :
\href{http://amor.cms.hu-berlin.de/~schulzgu/gentri/#mieteaenderung}{Click here}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works like a charm. thx @RHertel!